# Concurrency solutions for file based databases?

Tags: database, sqlite, leveldb

I am aware one of the biggest challenges with using file based databases is performance, especially concurrency.

But an app I'm trying to build requires that I use a file based database (such as LevelDB or Sqlite) so I am trying to find a way to get around this issue even if it means I need to make some compromises.

What are some approaches for improving performance/concurrency for file based DBs?

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5 and http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Comment: according to leveldb, you can compromise on read and write performance by increase the limit of level 0 file numbers. i don't think there's a common way to do that for what you called 'file based DBs'.

Comment: @sel-fish could you share a link on that?

Comment: @Vlad i don't think i can find a link, but by 'increase the limit of level 0 file numbers', level can get a higher write performance can be deduced by its storage principle